# Force S3 PDF to be viewed in browser instead of download

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

So you can force a download by using `Content-Disposition: attachment`

`Content-Disposition: inline` is the default and should display in the browser, and it does in fact work with most files like PNG, JPG, etc.

But for some reason somehow when generating a presigned URL from S3, PDF files will always force download even if I don't use the content-disposition: attachment header.

I want to be able to make the PDF open in the browser when the browser allows it

I am using the presigned URL generate call from S3 client http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURLJavaSDK.html

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Check you file's metadata and remove **Content-Disposition** entry from that file. and set **content type** according to the file type.

Like for 
text file **Content-Type**='text/plain'

image png **Content-Type**='image/png'

pdf **Content-Type**=application/pdf

pdfxml **Content-Type**=application/vnd.adobe.pdfxml

If your file's Content-Type is binary/octet-stream then it will download instead of display.

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

You have to set your putObject params as follows to view pdf instead of download.

```
 params = {
        Bucket: process.env.S3_BUCKET,
        Key: <fileName>,
        Body: <fileContent>,
        ContentDisposition:"inline",
        ContentType:"application/pdf"
    };
```

Answer (score 2):

You also need to set the `Content-Type` correctly. The browser will check the content-type value, and if it isn't something it knows how to display it will always just download the file.

Answer (score 1):

For those who are likely to make camel casing mistakes very often. Please check the Camel casing of the ContentType and ContentDisposition.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide both these meta data inorder to view the file instead of download:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment
Content-Type: application/pdf
```